# PHP8.1 on debian: undefined symbol: crypto_core_ristretto255_scalar_invert

Tags: php

I installed PHP8.1 with some additional modules. An undefined symbol error is displayed when calling `php --version`:

```
$ php --version
php: symbol lookup error: php: undefined symbol: crypto_core_ristretto255_scalar_invert
```

What am I missing? The Installation commands I've been using:

```
$ sudo apt install php8.1
$ sudo apt install php8.1-cli php8.1-common php8.1-curl php8.1-mbstring php8.1-mysql php8.1-xml php8.1-zip libapache2-mod-php php-imagick php-gd php8.1-mysql php8.1-gd
```

System: Debian 11.5, Kernel 5.10

Edit: Additional information about PHP8.1

```
$ ldd /usr/bin/php8.1 | grep crypto
        libcrypto.so.1.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.1 (0x00007f5f05362000)
$ ldd /usr/bin/php8.1 | grep sodium
        libsodium.so.23 => /usr/local/lib/libsodium.so.23 (0x00007fda8ef19000)
$ ll /usr/local/lib/libsodium.so.23
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root staff 19 Mar 10  2019 /usr/local/lib/libsodium.so.23 -> libsodium.so.23.2.0
$ ll /usr/local/lib/libsodium.so.23.2.0
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root staff 2.1M Mar 10  2019 /usr/local/lib/libsodium.so.23.2.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a solution. There are two versions of `libsodium.so.23` installed on my system:

```
/usr/local/lib/libsodium.so.23.2.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsodium.so.23.3.0
```

`libsodium.so.23.2.0` doesn't support `crypto_core_ristretto255_scalar_invert` where as `libsodium.so.23.3.0` does.

In order to let PHP8.1 use `libsodium.so.23.3.0` I had to remove the initial softlink `/usr/local/lib/libsodium.so.23` (see `ldd` output from my initial post).

Now PHP8.1 uses the latest library (no additional commands used):

```
$ ldd /usr/bin/php8.1 | grep sodium
        libsodium.so.23 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsodium.so.23 (0x00007f07bc320000)
```

Comment: Please note that the softlink `/usr/local/lib/libsodium.so.23` was set again after a `sudo apt upgrade`. I do not know who or why the softlink was re-established - I removed it once again.

Answer (score 0):

I solve this by updating PHP to latest version on Arch Linux, since I was stopping PHP update on `pacman.conf` file